# randomly seek a small sequence of a particular length in a larger sequence in python

Tags: python, random

I want to randomly seek a subsequence of length 4 from a larger sequence.

I tried the following code:

```
import system
import random

    X = 'ATGCATGCTAGCTAGTAAACGTACGTACGTACGATGCTAATATAGAGGGGCTTCGTACCCCTGA'
    Y = [random.choice(X) for i in range(4)]
    print(Y)
```

But it selects 4 distinct elements from X and not a sequence of length 4 in continuity.

Comment: *"it selects 4 distinct elements from X"* - that's exactly what you asked for! Did you want something like `start = random.randrange(len(X) - 4); X[start:start+4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to choose a character from `X` using `random.choice` , if you want a sequence of length 4 in continuity, choose an index between 0 and length of `X` - 4 , and take the 4 elements from that index. Example -

```
>>> X = 'ATGCATGCTAGCTAGTAAACGTACGTACGTACGATGCTAATATAGAGGGGCTTCGTACCCCTGA'
>>> import random
>>> i = random.randint(0,len(X)-4)
>>> X[i:i+4]
'TGCA'
>>> i
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could randomly select a starting index, then use slicing to extract that substring

```
def random_slice(s, n):
    index = random.randint(0, len(s)-n)
    return s[index : index + n]

>>> random_slice(X, 4)
'GCTA'
>>> random_slice(X, 4)
'CGTA'
>>> random_slice(X, 4)
'TATA'
>>> random_slice(X, 4)
'AGCT'
```